# Autofilling based of value map in QField

Tags: attribute-table, qfield, calculate-values, values, properties

Is it possible to prepare a Value Map with autofilling? I have a list of almost 500 plant names and it is difficult to find correct name on my device (phone with Qfield) while scrolling. Is it possible to prepare a value map but with typing? For example I start to type "Fra.." and all names with Fra.. like Fraxinus etc appear on list?

Comment: This seem to only work if you use the "value relation" widget rather than the "value map" widget and check the "use completer" box (you will need to use a table with your plant names list but you probably already used one to fill the value map so you most likely only have to add it to you project).

Comment: @J.R i uploaded list of species as csv file in Value Map widget. How to prepare it in Value Relation?

Comment: Just add your csv as a table in your project with "add delimited text layer" then select it as layer in the value relation widget and set both key and value column to the column containing the plant name then check the use completer box ( you may also want to check the Allow NULL value)